# Improper integral with residue theorem why is condition no real zeros needed?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, residue-calculus

If I apply the residue theorem to evaluate the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ then all necessary conditions are fulfilled except that f has no real singularities. It‘s clear that the principal value doesn‘t exist but the only meaningful value of the integral would have to be infinite, but with the residue theorem the integral should be zero. So is the Problem here that the curve which is used to derive the theorem doesn’t include the singularity or where else is the problem?

Comment: The residue theorem's proof assumes continuity of the function along the contour. $1/x^2$ is discontinuous and even undefined at $x=0$ which lies along the path $-\infty,\infty$

Comment: This real integral cannot be given an ordinary meaning, not to speak of a value: it is what is call a "PV" (Principal Value) or better a "FP" (Finite Part) integral with no meaning outside the theory of distributions. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2887408) for more

Comment: **"then all necessary conditions are fulfilled except that $f$ has no real singularities."** No, the conditions are not fulfilled. Look carefully. $f$ has a singularity at $0,$ and the contour $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\,\gamma(t)=t$ passes through that singularity. So the contour integral of $f$ over said contour does not exist. The residue theorem does not imply the integral should be $0,$ because the pole is part of the contour, and not enclosed by it.

Comment: This is a standard situation. One uses a contour that half-encloses the singularity, rather than taking the straight line path.

Comment: @TedShifrin That would still result in divergence, and besides, that does not answer the question. The question being asked is about the applicability of the residue theorem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contour you take will go from $-N$ to $-\epsilon$, around the semicircle $\gamma_\epsilon$ (clockwise) to $\epsilon$, then to $N$, then around the large semicircle $\Gamma_N$ (counterclockwise). So you get
$$\int_{-N}^{-\epsilon} f(z)\,dz + \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} f(z)\,dz + \int_\epsilon^N f(z)\,dz + \int_{\Gamma_N} f(z)\,dz = 0.$$
In the limit, we get
$$P.V. \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} = -\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} f(z)\,dz = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \frac2\epsilon = \infty.$$

I should comment that one often sees applications similar to this. The standard one is the computation of $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ by integrating $\dfrac{e^{iz}}z$. Taking the contour I suggested gives the result (with a little bit of work justifying why the limit of the integral over $\Gamma_N$ goes to $0$). Of course, this function has a simple pole at $0$.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since the question is asking about the applicability of the residue theorem in the context of evaluating this integral.

Comment: Everyone should review the application of the residue theorem when calculating a P.V. and a singularity is on the contour. Taking the path I described, one typically picks up *half* the residue (times $2\pi i$) — when there is no further singularity.

Comment: @Angel I don't agree : the OP has to be informed that, prior to undertake an integral in the complex plane, he/she must verify that the "targeted" real integral makes sense...

Comment: @JeanMarie How does that disagree with anything I said? I agree that the targeted real integral should be checked, but everyone here is in agreement that the integral as such does not exist. The consideration of $P.V$ comes *after* the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $$f(z)=\frac1{z}.$$ If the contour of integration were to be closed curve enclosing $0,$ then according to the residue theorem, the integral would be $0.$ However, the contour you have does not enclose $0,$ but passes through $0,$ and a contour cannot pass through $0$ for the integral. Therefore, the integral does not exist, which is to say, $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable over said contour.

Comment: You never integrate *through* the singularity. This situation shows up repeatedly in complex analysis.

Comment: @TedShifrin That fails to properly address my answer.

Comment: Why should the integral over closed curve enclosing 0 be zero? @Angel

Comment: @Silas Because the residue at $0$ of $f$ is $0.$ Also, you can evaluate this without using the residue theorem, just do the usual contour integration with a closed curve containing $0.$ For example, $\gamma:[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},$ $\gamma(t)=e^{it}.$ Hence $$\oint_{\gamma}\frac1{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-2it}ie^{it}\,\mathrm{d}z=i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-it}\,\mathrm{d}z=0.$$

Comment: Ah thanks! I thought you meant the integral $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z} \mathrm{d}z$ is zero.